# How do I display only certain data types with ngFor in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor, typescript-types

I'm iterating over the array called "fruits", containing objects of type "FruitService" - a class I defined and want to display each element, but after deleting them (I realize this is weird-no db) they become of type "undefined" contaminating my array. I don't want these to display (they show up as blank) so I want to display only "FruitService" objects. How do I do that?

```
<ul>

<li *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
{{ fruit.name }}  price: {{ fruit._price }}   qty: {{ fruit.qty }}

</ul>
```

Comment: How do you delete these items ? Your array should not contain undefined values. So you should better fix your delete-method, instead of trying to filter in in the HTML (which is possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is better handled off in the controller. Ideally, there should be no `undefined` elements in the array when the corresponding element is removed. They should actually be removed from the array.

That said, you could do a simple check in the template to see if the element is defined before rendering them

```html
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
    <li *ngIf="fruit">
      {{ fruit.name }}  price: {{ fruit._price }}   qty: {{ fruit.qty }}
    </li>
  </ng-container>
</ul>
```

The `ng-container` tag would be commented out in the final DOM and won't generate additional elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can either filter them with a pipe or by checking if they are truthy:

```html
<ul>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
    <li *ngIf="!!fruit">
      {{ fruit.name }}  price: {{ fruit._price }}   qty: {{ fruit.qty }} 
    </li>
  <ng-container>
</ul>
```

Solution with a pipe:

```html
<ul>
  <ng-container>
    <li *ngFor="let fruit of fruits | defined">
      {{ fruit.name }}  price: {{ fruit._price }}   qty: {{ fruit.qty }} 
    </li>
  <ng-container>
</ul>
```

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'defined'
})
export class DefinedPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: any[]): any[] {
    return array.filter(element => !!element);
  }
}
```